# Unresolved Statement - Using Toast in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm new with android programming and when I use the following code to show a toast on the android studio and there's the error "Unresolved statement"... what can I do to fix it ? (BTW I imported the toast library too)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
    Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MY TOAST MESSAGE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: move yout toast line into oncreate() method

Comment: remove    `Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MY TOAST MESSAGE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);`

Answer (score 1):

Change the line to

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MY TOAST MESSAGE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And move it to oncreate method

Answer (score 1):

Try this and move it into onCreate:

```
Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,"myText",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Error:(24, 88) error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to Toast
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.ror output for details.

Comment: Sorry, you must use
Toast t = Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,"myText",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
t.show();

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add code **after** return statement and you need to move your code into `OnCreate`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MY TOAST MESSAGE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have lines as follows at `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`

```
 return true;
    Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MY TOAST MESSAGE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

after a returns statement why to use Toast . no meaning here, remove or place it somewhere else where it can be reachable and should not be after the return statement.

writing like `Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MY TOAST MESSAGE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

does not make sense as method show() returns void so why to assign it to a Toast??

Answer (score 0):

You **do not** need to create instance of `Toast` just put this,

```
Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "My Toast Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```